# Example where $I,J$ are $p$-primary ideals, but $I+J$ is not $p$-primary.

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

Assume that $R$ is a noetherian ring. I am looking for an example where $I$ and $J$ are $p$-primary $R$-ideals, but $I+J$ is not $p$-primary. I am pretty sure there are no such examples for monomial ideals over a polynomial ring (over a field), or for ideals in a PID. Also, I know that $p$ is the unique minimal prime of $I+J$, so that any other associated prime must contain $p$.

Comment: $\newcommand{\rad}{\operatorname{rad}}$This boils down to finding primary $I,J$ such that $I+J$ is not primary, correct? Because if $\rad(I)=\rad(J)=p$, then $\rad(I+J)=\rad(I)+\rad(J)=p$.

Comment: Well, if they are primary to different primes, then it isn't too hard to find examples where the sum is not primary.  So the question I think is really about the zero divisors in $R/(I+J)$.

Comment: To add more to your comment, just because the radical is prime does not mean it is p-primary. Take, for example, $I=(x^3,xy)$. The radical is $(x)$, but $(x,y)$ is also an associated prime.

Comment: I feel that it should have a counter-example for your question but I have no one. I suggest you ask this question at MO.

Comment: Thanks @PhamHungQuy, I will do that.

Comment: I posted an answer on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/258808/i-j-are-p-primary-ideals-but-ij-is-not/258813#258813

Comment: Sorry! I think it never happened. Please check my proof. $rad(rad(I)+rad(J))=rad(I+J)=rad(P+P)=rad(P)=P$? what is wrong?

Comment: @Soulostar please see the comment above: the radical being prime does not guarantee that it is primary. You could have other primes containing that minimal prime (after all, the radical of an ideal is the intersection of the $\textit{minimal}$ primes).

Comment: I see. Thank you so much